Error while compiling tidy.el
I downloaded tidy.el, an emacs package providing an interface to the HTML tidy program on this site:
https://www.html-tidy.org/

I encountered an error while trying to follow the installation instructions contained within tidy.el.  The file contains this timestamp:
Time-stamp: <2002-09-30 13:16:23 kahlil>

I placed the downloaded file in ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp.  I next loaded it into a buffer using find-file.  I then invoked emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load.  This resulted in about a page full of warnings, followed by this error message:
    ‘https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript’
  tidy.el: Error: Invalid read syntax: ")", 38, 54

Here are a few lines of tidy.el surrounding the line identified in the message:

I ran the emacs diff command to compare the code in tidy.el and the code given on the stackoverflow site and, apart from spaces, found no differences.
Column 54 in line 38 is the space following the closing parenthesis ).
I look forward to being able to use tiny.el if someone can help me get by this compilation error.


Try to determine whether the error is from the byte-compiler or from loading the *.elc. 2. Open the *.elc and check whether it has such a problem. 3. Try manually loading tidy.el. Try manually loading tidy.elc. Post whatever additional info you get in your question, for more info / clarification.


The lines shown are Javascript, so they are NOT lines of tidy.el which is an Elisp program. And just to make sure, I downloaded tidy.el and looked: these lines come from something else. BTW, I also byte-compiled and loaded both tidy.el and the compiled version tidy.elc. The compilation produces a bunch of warnings which can be ignored on a first pass - the loading went without a hitch. I think you are trying to byte-compile the wrong file.

Thanks for these responses.  I now realize that I must have downloaded some kind of web page, not the tidy.el file.  Once I did it right, it compiled just fine
